# Fantasy book series, army of skeletons in one of the books

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a fantasy book series that I read at least 15 years ago, and may have been from earlier than that.

It was mostly about a relatively small and poor northern kingdom. One of the books was about a powerful sorcerer raising an army of skeletons and attacking the kingdom. After being defeated the sorcerer kidnapped the main mage of the kingdom (a woman) and planned to sacrifice her but was killed.

The evil sorcerer was not a human I think but something like a giant reptile, a dragon maybe.

Comment: Hi there - do you have any further information? How long ago did you read it? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Any names of characters, locations, etc?

Comment: I read it at least 15 years ago so it is not from this century. Unfortunately there is not much that I remember after so many time :)

I hope that skeleton army is distinct enough, though Skeleton Warriors article on tvtropes does not have it :(

Comment: Unfortunately skeleton armies (or similar) are very common, and go by many different names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the book series [Chronicles of Prydain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Prydain) by Lloyd Alexander which was published from 1964 to 1968, and features five novels:

- [The Book of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Three)
- [The Black Cauldron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Cauldron_(novel))
- [The Castle of Llyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Castle_of_Llyr)
- [Taran Wanderer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taran_Wanderer)
- [The High King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_High_King)

The skeleton army that you refer to is the Cauldron Born, undead creatures that come from the Black Cauldron. The death lord Arawn is a magician shape changer, and his war leader is the Horned King. Arawn tries to use the army to conquer the describedly small kingdom of Prydain, and is thwarted by Taran and a princess (Eilonwy) and a couple of other companions. The princess also gets kidnapped in the third book, Castle of Llyr.

The only item I can't match is the reptile, but it's been a long time since I read the books, that may be a detail I am forgetting.

Comment: Thank you, but Cauldron Born do not look like skeletons, there is no dragon-like creatures and princess is memory charmed - which did not happen in my book. Still the number of common points is amusing.